# Failed dependency by installing self made rpm package

Tags: packaging, software-packaging

I'm trying to create an RPM (redhat) package to install nagios on a redhat system. Everything goes well but when I try to install the package I get

> Failed dependencies:
>
> perl (Net::SNMP) is needed by nagios-1-1.x86_64

I don't even know why it requires this, it doesn't look to be a necessary package to me. Anyone who had this problem before?

Here is the .spec

```
%define debug_package %{nil}
%define _prefix /usr/local/nagios

Summary: Nagios blabla
Name: nagios
Version: 1
Release: 1
License: PROPRIETARY
Group: Applications/Accessories
Source: nagios-1.tar.gz
Packager: Nicholas Lievens <lievens.nicholas@gmail.com>
Requires: gcc gcc-c++ glibc glibc-common glibc-devel gd gd-devel php53 php53-cli php53-mysql php53-gd php53-pdo graphviz httpd libdbi-dbd-mysql libdbi-devel mysql mysql-server mysql-devel git

%description
Nagios!
%prep
%setup
%build
make all
%install
make install
make install-init
make install-config
make install-commandmode
make install-webconf
make install-devel
htpasswd -b -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.user nagiosadmin nagiosadmin
%files
%{_prefix}/var
%{_prefix}/var/spool/checkresults
%{_prefix}/etc
%{_prefix}/bin
%{_prefix}/sbin
%{_prefix}/libexec
%{_prefix}/lib
%{_prefix}/include/nagios
%{_prefix}/share
```

Comment: What does your spec file look like? How are you trying to install your RPM? `yum` or `rpm -[Ui]vh` ?

Comment: I will post the spec after the weekend, i'm trying to install it using rpm -i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a `requires` for `perl` in your spec file. When you post it we can have a look.

If you run `sudo yum localinstall /path/to/your.rpm --nogpgcheck` should resolve these dependencies for you in the installation.

Comment: I updated my post with the .spec file, i'll try the yum method also

Comment: tried the yum localinstall. It downloaded some packages but after that I get the message Package nagios-1-1.x86_64.rpm is not signed

Comment: I added AutoReqProv: no . This solves it for now I think. The rpm works this way, nagios doesn't but I think we forgot some files in the .spec file

Comment: I've added a `--nogpgcheck` flag to avoid the "not signed" message. How about now?

Comment: well I don't know but it worked by adding the AutoReqProv: no in .spec